# Using encryption over NAS

Tags: encryption, raid, nas

I have a local cluster which connect to a Synology NAS (918+) which holds data.  I would like to have the data on the NAS encrypted.

The machines all run Ubuntu and mount the NAS with:

```
mount -t cifs //ip-to-nas/storage_bucket_name -o username=username,password=password,uid=1000,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 /mount_point_directory
```

Can I use cifs to mount storage which uses encryption?

If not, what are my alternatives, given the use case?

(I also want to use a RAID 1-style mirroring, but Synology do not support encryption with RAID 1 - which of the Synology formats would you recommend for this use case?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synology does support file-level encryption with RAID1. I have a Synology DS216j (lowest multi-bay model in their lineup) with 2 drives in RAID 1 and a few encrypted shared folders.

You can create encrypted shared folders in the Control Panel. They are unlockable through the Control Panel by entering a password. You can also configure Synology to unlock them automatically using keys stored on a connected USB drive. RAID is irrelevant because it's completely transparent - drives in a RAID are exposed to the system as a single block device, just like a plain drive.

If you want a per-user encryption solution instead, then that's a different question. Synology and RAID are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there's likely to be an issue connecting to an encrypted folder with cifs ?

Comment: Synology exposes it as a regular shared folder. From external clients' perspective there's no difference.

Comment: While the folder is "in use" (ie mounted), is it at that point encrypted?  If someone steals the NAS while the folder is mounted, will they be able to access the data from a different location?  Or is the decryption handled during reads?

Comment: All files in the shared folder are encrypted all the time. Data is decrypted on the fly when it's being read

Comment: Thanks.  Finally... if the decryption key is on an external location (such as a machine on the same network as the NAS, as told by the Synology Key Manager), how does the NAS read that key file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: If the folder is encrypted, then reads must provide the key to decrypt.  But the key is held on another file system, so the NAS OS must have access to that filesystem somehow.  I don't provide it with access, so I'm wondering what the mechanism is.

Comment: You either unlock the volume manually after each boot by entering the password or you dedicate a USB drive to Synology Key Manager which unlocks it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104083/discussion-between-omroth-and-gronostaj).